# Checkout billing address getting blank in magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento-2.2.5, billing-address, coupon-codes

I'm getting issue on checkout when I apply coupon code on checkout cart or checkout shipping page at the end of checkout payment page I'm getting issue with my billing address  same as shipping getting only 2 things once pin code or second country name

[image]

Comment: please check in console if you are getting any error.

Comment: in billing-address.js there is function updateAddress which call setBillingAddressAction which is called through Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address.js check in that

Comment: When I apply a coupon then billing address only get the pin code and country name

Comment: Otherwise, its working fine

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to the module Cash on delivery. See [here](https://github.com/it4mage/CashOnDelivery/issues/33) for the solution.